# C push function in stack implementation using doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to make a push function, but for some reason I can't make it work. The `(*top)->next` still points to `top` after running the function.

Here is the function:

```
int isEmpty(StackNode *top)
{
    if(!top->current)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void push(StackNode **top, Node *node)
{
    if (isEmpty(*top))
    {
        (*top)->current = node;
    }
    else
    {
        StackNode *newStackNode = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
        if (newStackNode)
        {
            newStackNode->current = node;
            newStackNode->prev = NULL;
            (*top)->prev = newStackNode;
            newStackNode->next = (*top);
            (*top) = newStackNode;
            printf("%p\n%p\n", (*top), (*top)->next);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the definition of structs Node and StackNode:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    State state;
    Move action;
    struct Node *parent;
    unsigned int depth;
    unsigned int fValue;
}
Node;

typedef struct StackNode
{
    Node *current;
    struct StackNode *prev;
    struct StackNode *next;
}
StackNode;
```

Comment: Show the stack definition. For example it is unclear what is top->current.

Comment: The definition of the structure struct Node does not make a sense in the context of the stack.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the struct Node is for the nodes of represnting the states in a 8-puzzle game

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük doesn't `newStackNode->next = (*top);` do that? so when i do `(*top) = newStackNode;`, the `(*top)->next` points to the previous StackNode the `(*top)` was pointing to?

Comment: @pi3.14 i corrected that, i was too fast, i admit, i posted an answer, have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

```
newStackNode->next = (*top);
(*top) = newStackNode;
```

'*top' is now 'newStackNode' and the field 'next' points to '*top'.

Push Front:

```
newStackNode->prev = NULL;
newStackNode->next = (*top);
(*top)->prev = newStackNode;
```

Push Back:

```
newStackNode->prev = (*top);
newStackNode->next = NULL;
(*top)->next = newStackNode;
```

Finally:

```
(*top) = newStackNode;
```

The initial element (first of all created Nodes) should have prev and next point to NULL.

And all should be fine. It is still unclear for me which 'top' you mean, do you want a circular list, so that the next of the last element points to the first element and the previous of the first element points to the last?